# Average kinetic energy of gases

Tags: ideal-gas, kinetic-theory

Is the average kinetic energy per molecule of all ideal (mono, di and poly atomic) gases 3/2kT or is this just the translational kinetic energy per molecule?

Answer (score 0):

$\frac{3}{2}kT$ is only translational kinetic energy. If it is diatomic or polyatomic molecule, there is also rotational kinetic energy and the formula is $$<K>=\dfrac{f}{2}kT$$
where $f$ is degree of freedom